# Webscrape using for loop into data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, web-scraping

I feel like I am close with this but cannot find the right solution.  I want to scrape tables from multiple pages and save the results into one final data frame.  All the tables will have the same structure.  My code is below with a sample of the loop (realistically there are potentially 1,000 pages). When I run the code on a single page I can get the result but I cannot figure out the loop or how to save the loop results into a data frame. See what I am doing below, any help appreciated!!

```
library(textreadr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

for (event in (803:806)){
  url<-paste0('http://profightdb.com/cards/wwf/monday-night-raw-', event,'.html')
  webpage<-read_html(url)
  tbls_ls<-webpage %>%
    html_nodes('table') %>%
    .[[2]] %>%
    html_table(fill=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps save the results as a list of data frames.

```
library(textreadr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

tbls_ls <- vector(4, mode="list") # Initialize the list
i <- 1 # Initialize the index

for (event in (803:806)){
  url <- paste0('http://profightdb.com/cards/wwf/monday-night-raw-', event,'.html')
  webpage <- read_html(url)

  tbls_ls[[i]] <- webpage %>%
    html_nodes('table') %>%
    .[[2]] %>%
    html_table(fill=TRUE)

  i <- i+1  # Update the index
}
```

---

```
class(tbls_ls) # "list"
names(tlbs_ls) <- 803:806  # Name the elements
tbls_ls[1]
$`803`
  no.                        match      match                           match duration
1   1                     Yokozuna def. (pin)                     Koko B Ware    03:45
2   2 Rick Steiner & Scott Steiner def. (pin) Executioner #1 & Executioner #2    03:00
3   3           Shawn Michaels (c) def. (pin)                        Max Moon    10:30
4   4               The Undertaker def. (pin)                  Damien Demento    02:26
```